# ¿Como colocar todos los dias y su nombre, usando fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

Leyendo la documentacion de [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) no encontre la forma de poner todos los dias y el nombre de cada dia como header, alguien me podria ayudar?

Intente lo siguiente pero los nombres de los dias me salen al costado y yo quiero arriba

```
$(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaFourDay',
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'agendaDay,agendaFourDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2020-12-01'
    views: {
      agendaFourDay: {
        type: 'agenda',
        duration: { days: 31 } // Aqui coloco los dias que quiero pero me siempre empiezadel dia actual
      }
    }
  });

});
```

La imagen solo es referencial y es a lo que quiero lograr
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quieres lograr lo que esta haciendo el primer demo de [esta pagina](https://fullcalendar.io/#demos)?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera no es igual al demo, lo que quiero esta como mi imagen (los dias de corrido 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...31), en el demo seleccionando `week` aparece de corrido, dia y nombre en una celda, ademas que eso esta usando `scheduler` y es de paga